# How to stop a function without closing the application?

Tags: python, pyqt5

So, I want to close the function on_click_on_start which has while loop in it. And, dont want to close the window after hitting the stop button. Right now, I was using `sys.exit()` which crashed the program for some reason but, when I used only `quit()` it was closing the entire app. I am doing this on pyQt5. I am noob to GUI so please help me out. This is extra text which I have added so that I can post the question. Please ignore this.

```
import res1
import res
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import os
import pyaudio
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
import time


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 600))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Californian FB")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setMouseTracking(True)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(
            "../../../../Pictures/ugo_trans.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.Backgroundimage = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Backgroundimage.setEnabled(True)
        self.Backgroundimage.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(9, 9, 782, 582))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(
            self.Backgroundimage.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.Backgroundimage.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.Backgroundimage.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 600))
        self.Backgroundimage.setStyleSheet("")
        self.Backgroundimage.setText("")
        self.Backgroundimage.setPixmap(
            QtGui.QPixmap(":/newPrefix/Untitled-1.png"))
        self.Backgroundimage.setScaledContents(True)
        self.Backgroundimage.setObjectName("Backgroundimage")
        self.Start = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Start.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 240, 221, 111))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.Start.setFont(font)
        self.Start.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
                                 "color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.Start.setObjectName("Start")
        self.Stop = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Stop.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(510, 240, 221, 111))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.Stop.setFont(font)
        self.Stop.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
                                "color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.Stop.setObjectName("Stop")
        self.Title = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Title.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 70, 361, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(48)
        self.Title.setFont(font)
        self.Title.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                 "background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 60);")
        self.Title.setObjectName("Title")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.Start.clicked.connect(self.on_click_on_start) # button pressed on start
        self.Stop.clicked.connect(self.on_click_on_stop) # button pressed on stop and it only stops the on_click_on_start

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def on_click_on_start(self):
        CHUNK = 2**11
        RATE = 48016

        p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=RATE, input=True,
                        frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

        start = time.time()

        while 1:
            data = np.fromstring(stream.read(CHUNK), dtype=np.int16)
            peak = np.average(np.abs(data))*2
            bars = 100*peak/2**16
            if bars > 1:
                pyautogui.keyDown("NUM0")
                start = time.time()
                print('down')

            else:
                pyautogui.keyUp("NUM0")
                print('up')
                if time.time() - start > 5:
                    stream.stop_stream()
                    stream.close()
                    p.terminate()
                    break

    def on_click_on_stop(self):
        # Help me with this function

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Talk to Mute"))
        self.Start.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start"))
        self.Stop.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Stop"))
        self.Title.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Talk to Mute"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally using variables is easiest way to manage status. You can use variable for update running status.

```
running_status = false
```

Use like

```
self.running_status = true
```

in on_click_on_start.

Use

```
self.running_status = false
```

in on_click_on_stop. So now you can call your function if running_status is true.

Comment: Suggesting a global (which is rarely a good suggestion to begin with) when an instance attribute could and *should* be used instead, is a **terrible suggestion**. Please, remove that global statement and use something like `self.running_status` instead.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my mistake. @musicamante

Comment: You should also correct the introduction paragraph, as it might result confusing (since you're not using globals anymore) and the first phrase is also wrong: generally, using global variables is the easiest way to get into trouble and bugs that are often very hard to track.